# r - remove last but one character from every field

Tags: regex, r, string, gsub, substr

the substr() function in R can isolate any character by position e.g.

```
substr(df$10,2,3)
```

or by using `nchar()` it is possible to work backwards from the end of the field to isolate a character in a position such as last but one using:

```
substr(df$10,nchar(df$10)-2,nchar(df$10)-1)
```

however I would like to know how to simply remove the `last but one character` of every field for a column in a dataframe. I am having difficulty doing this. any help would be great!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "last but one"? Are you trying to remove everything except the second to last character?

Comment: can you show expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with `sub`:

```
x <- c("banana","republic")
sub(".(.)$","\\1",x)
[1] "banaa"   "republc"
```

What this does is match the last two characters in a string, and replace them with only the last one, which is captured in a capture group.

Comment: And a bit faster one: `sub("^(.*).(.)$", "\\1\\2", x)`