# remove last two characters only if it equals a condition

Tags: r, stringr

I have some carácter strings in R which look like:

```
strings <- c("agrima sl", "friends sl", "sociedad limitada", "sltyra sa", "sl qwrtyaga")
```

I want to remove the "sl" and "sa" from the strings but if I use the `str_replace_all(x, 'sl','')` it Will remove the characters which are not at the end of the text. i.e. it Will replace `sltyra sa` with `tyra sa`

How can I replace only the `sl` and `sa` characters which occur at the end of the text.

Comment: No, not exactly because this will remove the last n characters from all of the text. I want to only remove the `sl` and `sa` only if it occurs at the end of the text.

Comment: Do you want the space to be removed? If so, try `gsub("\\s(sl|sa)$", "", strings)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove specific last character from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45272047/remove-specific-last-character-from-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
str_replace_all(strings, 'sl$','')
```

Answer (score 1):

One option with `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(strings, '\\s*s[la]$')
#[1] "agrima"            "friends"           "sociedad limitada" "sltyra"            "sl qwrtyaga"
```